Getting this error while running flutter app - Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
When I try to run the flutter app, following error appears:
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':fluttertoast:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes     {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar,     org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: D:\softwares\SDK\platforms\android-    33\core-for-system-modules.jar.
Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android     Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\    <my_user_name>.gradle\caches\8.10\transforms\4d29fbaa4346204be836c2ef53b3528e-    d08e292b-46c8-4b2e-a9a3-70c9d6beb0d2\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules     java.base --output C:\Users\    <my_user_name>.gradle\caches\8.10\transforms\4d29fbaa4346204be836c2ef53b3528e-    d08e292b-46c8-4b2e-a9a3-70c9d6beb0d2\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin     system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


My project's sdk & dependancies:
environment:
sdk: "\>=3.1.0 \<4.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
http: ^0.13.4
sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
shared_preferences: 2.2.2
image_picker: 1.0.5
flutter_swiper_null_safety: 1.0.2
flutter_rating_bar: 4.0.1
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.20
cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
flutter_mobx: ^2.0.5
numeric_keyboard: ^1.0.0
flutter_secure_storage: 9.0.0
dio: ^4.0.4
flutter_math_fork: ^0.7.1
flutter_svg: 2.0.0+1
intl: 0.18.1
razorpay_flutter: 1.3.7
loading_indicator: ^3.1.1

dev_dependencies:
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
uses-material-design: true

build.gradle from android project:
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -\>
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk             in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
namespace "com.rohitkolar.townie_things"
compileSdkVersion 34
ndkVersion '28.0.12674087 rc2'

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = '17'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.rohitkolar.townie_things"
  https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-    configuration.
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

}`

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:2.0.21"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

Seems like razorpay dependency internally downloads fluttertoast
And it gives different errors when changed it's versions
I tried changing the razorpay versions but when I change it to below 1.3.7 it     gives namespace not specified error
what I found is gradle plugin version > 8 gives this namespace error, but     downgrading it doesn't work as the playstore doesn't accept app bundles built with SDK     version below 34
I also tried 'flutter clean', 'flutter pub cache clean' but no success
anybody encountered this problem before? please help
